# JQuery with ajax keeps posting multiple results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have many images on a page that show the status of the machine. If you click on the image then modal window opens and you can select new status. Status gets send via ajax to the DB. If I try to change another machines status the previous machines status gets changed also. Every status that I have touched gets resend every time as the last status that I selected.

It somehow creates an array of the machines I have changed and with every change posts all of them. Refresh of the page empties the array.

I think I need to use something similar to `unset` in php or move the inner click function outside of the first click function.

```
$(function() {
    $('#mach_status_dialog').hide();
    $('.mach_status').click(function(){
        var mach = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#mach_status_dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 500,
            title: 'Mach ' + mach + ' status'
        });

        $('.statuses').click(function(){
            var user = user;
            var class = $(this).attr('class');
            class = class.substring(10);
            var status = $(this).first().find('p').parent().text();
            var data_string = 'mach=' + mach + '&status=' + status + '&user=' + user;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_op_mach_status.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: data_string,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    var newSrc = 'images/Circle2_'+class+'_25.png';
                    console.log($('#'+mach+'.mach_status').attr('src', newSrc));
                    $('#'+mach+'.mach_status').attr('src', newSrc);
                    $('#'+mach+'.mach_status').attr('title', status);
                    $( "#mach_status_dialog" ).dialog('close');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('#mach_status_dialog').hide();
   $('.mach_status').click(function(){
    var mach = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#mach_status_dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        title: 'Mach ' + mach + ' status'
    });
});
$(document).on('click', '.statuses', function(){
        var user = user;
        var class = $(this).attr('class');
        class = class.substring(10);
        var status = $(this).first().find('p').parent().text();
        var data_string = 'mach=' + mach + '&status=' + status + '&user=' + user;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_op_mach_status.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: data_string,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                var newSrc = 'images/Circle2_'+class+'_25.png';
                console.log($('#'+mach+'.mach_status').attr('src', newSrc));
                $('#'+mach+'.mach_status').attr('src', newSrc);
                $('#'+mach+'.mach_status').attr('title', status);
                $( "#mach_status_dialog" ).dialog('close');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say, just move the `.click` event into the DOM ready callback. As it stands, every time you click on a `mach_status`, you are assigning a new click event handler. So if I click on `mach_status` 10 times, then click on a `statuses` link once, you'll get 10 AJAX requests.

If you only want to bind onto a `statuses` click when the user clicks on `mach_status`, add a class onto the element to tell it when it's ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mach_status_dialog').hide();
    $('.mach_status').click(function(){
        $(".statuses").addClass("ready");
        var mach = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#mach_status_dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 500,
            title: 'Mach ' + mach + ' status'
        });
    });
    $('.statuses.ready').click(function(){
        // Do AJAX
    });
});
```

Comment: and also `return false` after ajax call maybe?

Comment: @nickanor Maybe. Depends what `statuses` is. Could just be a `div` which does nothing after it's click event.

Comment: `statuses` is a `div` indeed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here...

```
$('.statuses').click(function(){
```

Every time you click on *.mach_status* element, it adds the event listener for all the statuses. You can changes this to

```
$(this).find('.statuses').click(function abc(){
   .
   .
   .
   this.removeEventListner('click', abc);
});
```

Notice How I am using the named functions and removing them from event queue once they are fired.